# Continuation of smooth functions on the bounded domain

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, approximation

Given a bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth function $f$ with bounded derivatives on $\Omega$, is it possible to extend $f$ to $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that it is smooth and compactly supported with given closed set $\Omega ' \supset \Omega$ ?

Comment: If your function has uniformly bounded derivatives to all orders, it is in fact real analytic, see http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Uniformly_bounded_derivatives_implies_globally_analytic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the question has been edited, the answer is yes, if the boundary of $\Omega$ is sufficiently smooth and there is an open set $G$ with $\overline{\Omega}\subset G\subset\Omega´$. Note at first, that $f$ can be continuously extended to $\overline{\Omega}$ by a classical topological result for uniformly continuous functions. And as the same is true for all partial derivatives, this extension is infinitely continuously differentiable.

The smooth extension to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$  is basically [Whitney's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem), see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131642/the-extension-of-smooth-function) question. And multiplication with a suitable function gives the compact support.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider $f: (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. You cannot extend $f$ over $0$. Generally, the problem of extending functions defined on open sets is hopeless.

Comment: Thanks. But, what if we impose additional condition that $f$ is is $\mathit{C}^\infty_b$ ?

Comment: You mean, $f$ is smooth and bounded? Still hopeless, consider $f: (0, 1) \to (0, 1)$, $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: No, All the the derivatives are bounded!

Comment: I edited the question. Please look in to it now.