# Extension of smooth extension with compact support

Tags: real-analysis

This question is related, but more restrictive than the one asked [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493516/existence-of-smooth-extension-of-a-function-defined-on-a-closed-interval) Namely, suppose you have a $C^k$ function on $[a,b]$. Can you extend it to a function in $C_c^k(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. a function of compact support on $\mathbb{R}$ ? The extension proposed in the other question doesn't seem to satisfy this condition of compact support.

Comment: In the trivial case of a function identically $1$ on $[a,b]$ it's ok, because we know there exists bump functions, i.e. smooth functions taking value $1$ on $[a,b]$ and zero say outside $[a-1,b+1]$. But for general functions in $C^k[a,b]$ ?

Comment: What happens if you multiply an arbitrary $C^k$ extension with a bump function?

Comment: Well, what happens is that I realize I'm a bit stupid.. Thank you !