# Can we extend a function on surface to a function on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I'm studying differential geometry right now. I've encountered a problem considering the definition of a function/differential forms on a surface $S \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Suppose we're given a $C^1$ function $f$ on $S$, can we say that there must be a restriction of some function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F|_{S} = f$. And, does this result hold for differential forms as well?

Comment: I assume you are requiring some kind of smoothness of $F$? Otherwise the result is trivial: just consider $1_S f$. If you require smoothness, the answer is yes, but higly non trivial. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131642/the-extension-of-smooth-function

Comment: Thank you!! Does this result also hold for differential forms?

Comment: Cover a neighborhood of $S$ with charts in which $S$ is represented by the $x$-$y$ plane. Extend your function to the entire chart by making it constant in $z$ direction. Then use a [smooth partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Smooth_partitions_of_unity) to stitch the extensions together.

Comment: Yes, what Conifold said is the way to do it — and if $S\subset\Bbb R^3$ is an embedded submanifold, then it has a tubular neighborhood, so you can just use that. Works for differential forms just fine, as well, with the same idea.